# How to do a basic join on two tables?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm working at learning SQLAlchemy, and I'm having trouble doing seemingly simple operations. Please forgive me if my question is primitive and basic, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to essentially join my two tables.

My tables are such:

```
class User(Base):

    """ Basic User definition """

    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(255))
    email = Column(Unicode(255), unique=True)
    username = Column(Unicode(255), unique=True)
    _password = Column('password', Unicode(60))

    contacts = relationship('Contact', backref='users')
    contact_groups = relationship('ContactGroups', backref='users')
    contact_group_users = relationship('ContactGroupUsers', backref='users')

class Contact(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'contacts'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer)
    contact_id = Column(Integer)

    __table_args__ = (ForeignKeyConstraint([contact_id], [User.id]), {})

class ContactGroups(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'contact_groups'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    group_name = Column(Unicode(255))

    contact_group_users = relationship('ContactGroupUsers', backref='contact_groups')

class ContactGroupUsers(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'contact_group_users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    group_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('contact_groups.id'))
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
```

I have my main `User` table. Users can add other users as `Contact`s. To help organize these contacts, they can create `ContactGroups`.

`Contact.user_id` and `Contact.contact_id` are supposed to be both foreign keys to `User.id`.

`ContactGroupUsers.group_id` is a foreign key to `ContactGroup.id`
And each `ContactGroupUser.user_id` is a foreign key back to that user's `User.id`.
(Maybe this a terrible way to do...it might be, but I am learning. Anyway.)

When I query for the contacts present in a particular group, I would like to retrieve all the rows where `filter(ContactGroupUsers.group_id == group_id).all()` and then from this, join each `ContactGroupUsers.user_id` to that user's entry in the `Contact` table. Hence, I would ultimately get a result which is:

```
ContactGroupUsers.group_id | (and then the information present in the contacts table for that user)
```

So, my final question, how can I join my two tables `ContactGroupUsers` and `Contacts` based on a `User.id`? Or, if there is an inherently superior way to do this, please point me in the right direction so I can at least learn appropriately.

Thanks for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far, after reading http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/tutorial.html#querying-with-joins ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are defining multiple foreign keys back to `User` in `Contact`, it might be better to define them as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy

class User( Base ):

    __tablename__       = 'user'

    id                  = Column( Integer, primary_key=True )

    contacts            = relationship( 'Contact',
        primaryjoin = 'foreign( User.id )=remote( Contact.user_id )',
        backref     = 'user'
    )
    contact_groups      = relationship( 'ContactGroup', backref='user' )
    contact_group_users = relationship( 'ContactGroupUsers', backref='user' )

    contact_users = association_proxy( 'contacts', 'contact' )

class Contact( Base ):

    __tablename__       = 'contact'

    id                  = Column( Integer, primary_key=True )

    user_id             = Column( Integer, ForeignKey( 'user.id' ) )
    contact_id          = Column( Integer, ForeignKey( 'user.id' ) )

    contact             = relationship( 'User',
        primaryjoin = 'foreign( Contact.contact_id ) = remote( User.id )',
        backref     = 'user_contacts'
    )

class ContactGroup( Base ):

    __tablename__       = 'contact_group'

    id                  = Column( Integer, primary_key=True )

    user_id             = Column( Integer, ForeignKey( 'user.id' ) )

class ContactGroupUser( Base ):

    __tablename__       = 'contact_group_user'

    id                  = Column( Integer, primary_key=True )

    group_id            = Column( Integer, ForeignKey( 'contact_group.id' ) )
    user_id             = Column( Integer, ForeignKey( 'user.id' ) )

    contact_group       = relationship( 'ContactGroup' )
```

Building out relationships in this format can be somewhat complicated and involve the user of `aliased` instances.  You could, for example, make a query as follows indicating all of a given user's contacts under some group_id:

```
original_user = aliased( User )

contacts = db.session.query( User )\
    .join( User.user_contacts )\
    .join( original_user, original_user.id == Contact.user_id )\
    .join( User.contact_group_users )\
    .join( ContactGroupUser.contact_groups ).filter(
        and_(
             original_user.id == user_id,
             contact_group.user_id == original_user.id,
             contact_group.group_id == group_id
        )
     ).all()
```

Comment: If you then want to go into the contact `User`'s information stored under the `Contact` record associating the two, you will want your query to read something like `contacts = db.session.query( User, Contact )`.  Then you can do `contacts[0].Contact` or `conacts[0].User` to get information from either table.